# Updating the position attribute directly of a Shape geometry breaks the texture on the Mesh. How do I fix the textures?

Tags: three.js

I try to make a wall with a window in it. I draw the corners of the wall and the corners of the window after, from the bottom left, counter clockwise. Then I manipulate the 4 vertex of the window via javascript and update the position attribute of the geometry accordingly. The window moves correctly but the textures are not. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I do after calculating the new positions array:

```
this.geometry.setAttribute("position", new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
```

Here is the full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wg1phnz6/45/

Comment: You have to re-compute uv coords for those 4 moving points of the window.

Comment: @prisoner849 could you please point me in the right direction on how to do it?

Comment: Your "window" doesn't have a texture, and your wall texture is repeating/tile-able. You probably don't need UVs at all, but instead you could adjust the texture scale and repeat factors.

Comment: If you DO want to use UVs, you will need to adjust the UV values for the vertices you are changing. Remember that UVs are percentages, so it should be easy to recalculate them based on the new vertex positions relative to the overall length of the wall.

Comment: @TheJim01 Thank You! If I later add a displacement map, is it true that I still wouldn't necesssarily need a UV coords?

Comment: Like with textures, you don't _need_ UVs, ***BUT*** (and this is a very big but), you might find that dealing with scaling and positioning the displacement map to accurately fit your model will be much more difficult without UVs.